# Redirect Incoming HTTPS Url to My Site's HTTPS Version

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, referrer

My client has a site http://www.sitename.com and also has a secure https://www.sitename version. For Google Analytics traffic reasons, he needs to make sure that any users coming from an https url be redirected to the secure version and NOT the insecure url.
What would be the proper way to do this via .htaccess? I searched here and online in general couldn't find a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to force https for achieving your use case. Add this to your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to only redirect incoming links that are https who click on a http link on our site to redirect to our https version. For example, if a user is coming from facebook (which is https) and clicks on one of our blog posts that is http, we want the http blog link to be redirected to https blog link. The above code you suggest redirects all traffic to https.

Comment: You cannot do a force https on random links for your site. This are the option available for you 1. Use https on your site and do not force it and integrate https link to Facebook articles. 2. Force https on whole website. 3. Force https on a ceratain folder on your web site and integrate the links that contain that folder in Facebook.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected as much.